# Why do I need to import collections in router file?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I'm building simple webs with meteor, just to get to know each other, and I'm playing with iron:router as router.

The "problem" I got is that in my meteorapp/lib/routes.js I need to import my collection file which is in meteorapp/imports/ui/reservations.js:

```
import { Reservations } from '../imports/api/reservations.js';
```

Otherwise I'm not able to reach it in the template, even though I imported it same line (different path) in the templage.js file like this:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
//collection Reservations
import { Reservations } from '../api/reservations.js';
import './roomSchedule.html';

Template.roomSchedule.onCreated(function roomScheduleOnCreated() {
  Meteor.subscribe('reservations');
});


Template.roomSchedule.helpers({

  allHours() {

    return Reservations.find();
  },

});
```

I don't know if this would help, meteor list output:

```
user@laptop:~/Documents/meteorApps/mymeteorApp$ meteor list
blaze-html-templates   1.1.2  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze
ecmascript             0.10.3* Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files
es5-shim               4.7.3  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
insecure               1.0.7  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes from the client
iron:router            1.1.2  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-base            1.3.0  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience      1.0.5  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                  1.4.3  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
reactive-var           1.0.11  Reactive variable
shell-server           0.3.1  Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command.
standard-minifier-css  1.4.1  Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js   2.3.2  Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                1.1.3  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
```

So it works... but don't know why... Thanks in advance to everyone.

Axel.

Comment: So what is the path of your `roomSchedule` template?

Comment: Thanks for the response Jankapunkt!
the path is meteorApp/imports/ui/ and there are those files:
body.html
body.js
roomSchedule.html
roomSchedule.js
roomsList.html
roomsList.js

Comment: The path that errors has a different name (reservation vs reservations). A good IDE or editor should prevent you from doing such mistake

Comment: Ok, I see what you say. I just recheck my code and it was same path (both in plural with "reservations"). I edited the question so no one else think that's the error. Still have the same error. Thanks for your time.

Comment: have you tried using the absolute import path style? ie `from '/imports/api/reservations'`

Comment: Because the answer is that you don't need to import collections in a router file

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the absolute path: `from '/imports/api/reservations'` and `from '/imports/api/reservations.js'` and never reached the collection. Also tried both in /lib/routes.js and worked...